# Wiil Paginate with jquery in ruby on rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I m developing an application, in which initaially i used mislav-will_paginate without using jquery. The application was running flawless. Now i have implemented jquery to call the controller n all. But will paginate not working. I guess there is some issue related to parameters. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can have look at [kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari) gem. Now a days, kaminari is mostly used for pagination in rails app. [Here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/254-pagination-with-kaminari) is a great tutorial to start pagination with kaminari.

Comment: Actually issue is On clicking on next link it is not calling the same action (But URL is displaying the action name), while it is calling "show" action with id as action name. Should I pass action and controller name explicitly.